# How to simplify a creation of a big data?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bigdata

I'm developing a game in Unity in 2 languages, German and English and I need to create many Events which can occur in the game everytime you age. But to create each Event manually, it could take up to 30 minutes because of the needed imagination and write-work.
Each Event has up to 4 Choices the player can make.
There are 2 different type of choices:

1. A Choice that will 100% succeed.
2. A Choice that may succeed or may not, based on the attribute value that is needed to succeed.

That's an example how an Event looks like in the .json File. But all choices of that are from Type 1. The Strings are keys which refer to a Translation Table.
[image: Event in .json File]

[image: Translation Table]

These are the two classes of Choice:

```
public class Choice {

    public string choiceName { get; private set; }
    public List<string> choiceResultsSuccess { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, float> affectedTraitsSuccess { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, float> affectedRelationshipsSuccess { get; private set; }
}

public class DependantChoice : Choice {
    public string attributeNameForSuccess { get; private set; }
    public float neededValueForSuccess { get; private set; }
    public List<string> choiceResultsFailure { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, float> affectedTraitsFailure { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, float> affectedRelationshipsFailure { get; private set; }
}
```

And this are possible Attributes that can be affected (The value Range is between -100 and 100):

```
// Skills
public const string CRIME = "crime";
public const string LANGUAGE = "language";
public const string CREATIVE_LOGICAL_THINKING = "creativeLogicalThinking";
public const string DEXTERITY = "dexterity";
public const string SOCIAL_COMPETENCE = "socialCompetence";
public const string ENGINEERING = "engineering";
public const string MEDICINE = "medicine";
public const string SCIENCE = "science";

// Attributes
public const string STRESS = "stress";
public const string FITNESS = "fitness";
public const string HEALTH = "health";
public const string MENTAL_WELLBEING = "mentalWellbeing";
public const string APPEARANCE = "appearance";
public const string INTELLIGENCE = "intelligence";
public const string MORALITY = "morality";
public const string REPUTATION = "reputation";
public const string SELF_CONFIDENCE = "selfConfidence";
```

Maybe one of you have already encountered this problem, where you have to create large Data but it would take too long to create them manually. Maybe using a script or something different.

I'm looking forward to read any suggestion to that or people who have handled such problems.

And ask any questions if you don't understand something.

Comment: By the looks of it, these events are basically the core of the game, so writing them is basically... the writing for your game? Sure, you could use an LLM to help you out, but that's taking all of the creative work out of it...

Comment: But creating more than 500 Events which each takes up to 30 Minutes is crazy, isn't it?

Comment: 250 hours, so about 33 full 7.5 hour workdays. Doesn't sound too bad for a writer of a game...

Comment: Of course if you can make the technical process faster by e.g. making it easier for yourself to input the data – for instance, write it in Google Sheets or Excel and write a program to convert this easier-edited form into the JSON, all the better.

Comment: I see, thanks for the feedback. I had to get an oppinion of someone else. I guess then I have to write it manually but look for an opportunity, which makes the insert easier